# Tracing Web API calls to database tables

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, web-services, trace

I'm currently looking at a codebase and trying to figure out what database tables are hit for specific API calls. I'd like a way to programmatically find out the specific tables being hit for an API call. The API seems to mainly hit a postgresql and mssql databse, with some calls also hitting a dynamo db. Unfortunately the API seems complicated, so I really don't want to deal with enabling logging in all of the projects that impact the API. I checked out some python libraries that created diagrams from python code, but they did not seem too helpful. Would it be feasible to change the logging in the databases to log complete queries for a time? I figure if I set up a test version of the APIs and databases with increased logging I can just hit the db with specific calls and then get the table info from the database logs.

Comment: So it could be any statement against as many as three different databases? But you aren't really sure which database(s) may or may not be utilized? Perhaps you need to rethink what you are asking because there is no chance anybody can offer much based on this incredibly vague description at this point.

Comment: Right, the two dbs of interest are the postgresql and msql db. The dynamo db is utilized for less calls and documentation for that is less important. I know what the specific databases called are, and I expect that I could redirect my API calls to specific databases.

Comment: But I'm not completely certain what calls hit what databases. I have a somewhat decent idea, but I don't want to depend on those assumptions for creating documentation. Also, the API is complicated, one call can span multiple different projects with different architecures and I don't have all of those projects up and running. I'm not completely comfortable with how api calls are routed through the backed. So adding logging in python codebase seems like it would be a time-intensive task. I'd much rather bypass that and just focus on the databases themselves if that was adequate.

Comment: Adequate for what exactly? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. You mention documentation...I would NOT be comfortable creating documentation from what I see happening in a database. I would create documentation from the code.

Comment: I'm wanting to document how the APIs  are connected with the databases. EG, if this database table is removed these API calls will fail as a result.

Comment: Then why not use the code as the basis? It would be pretty easy to miss something if you try looking at what happens in the database.